# What prevents a (theoretically ideal) railgun from being a perpetual motion device?

Tags: electromagnetism, thought-experiment, perpetual-motion

So, I understand the basics of how a railgun works - the current in the conducting rails and the armature sets up a magnetic field, which, via the Lorentz force acting on the current in the armature pushes the armature out of the loop formed by the rails, armature and power supply, accelerating it down the rails.

However, it seems to me like an ideal railgun, with zero-resistance rails and a constant current power supply, would be able to do more work on the projectile than the power supply supplies power. Here is my reasoning:

If the rails have zero resistance, then the total (DC) resistance remains the same no matter how far the projectile is along the rails. If the power supply supplies a constant voltage/current (and thus a constant amount of power), the armature should experience a constant acceleration. However, the rate at which mechanical work is done on the armature (in the railgun's rest frame), which is that force times the armature velocity, is constantly increasing, and would, naïvely, eventually exceed the amount of power (voltage*current) supplied by the power supply.

This is, of course, obviously unphysical, but none of my assumptions, those being zero-resistance frictionless rails of arbitrary length, no air resistance and a constant current/voltage electrical supply, seem to me to violate fundamental laws of physics.

So my question is: Where is my simple understanding of how a railgun works wrong? Which effect would end up limiting the projectile acceleration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a magnetostatic situation. As the projectile moves, the power supply must expend a portion of its power generating the magnetic field in the wake of the projectile. As the projectile moves faster and faster, more and more power is required to generate the magnetic field behind it. For a constant-power power supply, this means that as the projectile accelerates, the power spent on accelerating the projectile must decrease.

You can think about this as similar to the "back EMF" often referred to when talking about motors and generators.

From a forces perspective, as the projectile moves faster, the magnetic field in the area around it decreases (as it has yet to fully "catch up" to the projectile). So, although the current may stay the same, the force (which is dependent on the current and the magnetic field) nevertheless decreases.

Comment: a useful way to visualize this is by having a look at a device called a *homopolar generator* which is basically a railgun rolled into a circle, run in reverse. wikipedia has a good article on them.

Comment: Another useful thing is to study something called a *dynamic brake*, which is used to quickly stop electric motors from spinning once they are turned off. When a motor with a dynamic brake is turned off, its electrical terminals are disconnected from the power source and then shorted together. The motor is now a generator in which the kinetic energy of its spinning armature is converted into electrical power which flows through the short circuit. I'll submit these comments as a separate answer- NN

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thinking about it from the magnetodynamic point of view - as I would assume constant current means constant flux density, the total magnetic flux in the circuit would be proportional to the projectile's displacement, and so the rate at which the magnetic flux (and the energy stored in the magnetic field) increases is proportional to the projectile velocity. Thank you for your answer!

Also, does that mean that, since the power going into the field is ~proportional to projectile velocity, a railgun of a given power and configuration has a given absolute top speed?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the *dynamic brake* to be a useful tool to help me understand railgun dynamics, as follows.

The *dynamic brake* is used to quickly bring spinning electric motors to a stop once they are turned off. In a motor equipped with a dynamic brake, when you turn off the motor the motor is disconnected from the power source and then the motor's power terminals are short-circuited together.

The spinning motor is now an electric generator, with a very low impedance load (consisting of only the shorting switch contact resistance) connected to it. Since the load impedance is very low, the current flowing out of the generator and into the load is extremely high, and the kinetic energy of the motor armature is very quickly converted into electrical power which is dissipated as heat in the motor/generator's windings.

In this sense, a dynamic motor brake is a *railgun in reverse*.

The braking action is so extremely strong that a dynamically-braked motor driving a wood saw blade will stop turning so suddenly that the saw blade's inertia causes the nut holding the blade onto the motor shaft to instantly unscrew itself and the blade to be violently thrown out of the saw at lethal speed. To prevent this, the dynamic brake instead switches the motor terminals to a large load resistor which limits the current and causes the motor to slow down more gradually.

In a railgun, you want the acceleration to be as sudden as possible and so the "load resistance" is made as low as possible i.e., it consists of a big copper bar.